# Can't upload Picture in Django by user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I could upload pictures by the user, please help me to solve my problem.

view.py

```
def Detail(request, orid):
    data = cartData(request)
    cartItems       = data['cartItems']
    name            = request.user.profile
    form = Uplaodpic(instance=name)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Uplaodpic(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=name)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    orders          = Order.objects.filter(id=orid, name=name)
    OrderItems      = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=orid)
    pengirimans     = Pengiriman.objects.filter(order=orid)

    context = {'orders':orders, 'OrderItems':OrderItems,'pengirimans':pengirimans, 'form':form, 'cartItems':cartItems }
    return render(request, 'store/detail.html' ,context)
```

detail.html

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <input type="Submit" id="submit" name="Update Information" >
          </form>
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *

class Uplaodpic(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['bukti']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in your view.py

Add this code to first line in view.py

```
from .models import Order
```

and add this code to your function

```
def Detail(request, orid):
data = cartData(request)
cartItems       = data['cartItems']
name            = request.user.profile
form = Uplaodpic(instance=name)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Uplaodpic(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=name)
    if form.is_valid():
        form_data=Order.objects.create(name=form.cleaned_data.get('bukti')
        form_data.save()
orders          = Order.objects.filter(id=orid, name=name)
OrderItems      = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=orid)
pengirimans     = Pengiriman.objects.filter(order=orid)

context = {'orders':orders, 'OrderItems':OrderItems,'pengirimans':pengirimans, 'form':form, 'cartItems':cartItems }
return render(request, 'store/detail.html' ,context)
```

Comment: ValueError: Cannot assign "<InMemoryUploadedFile: bonbon-redheaded-guy-is-surprised-that-the-list-in-his-hands-is-empty-1.png (image/png)>": "Order.name" must be a "Profile" instance.                           
getting error like that

Comment: Cannot assign "<InMemoryUploadedFile: botany-6910792_1280.png (image/png)>": "Order.name" must be a "Profile" instance.

Comment: Change your varible form to form=Uploadpic(request.POST,request.FILES)

Comment: I am still getting the same problem sir  ></